# How to use regexreplace with LEFT

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've a column in which each row has multiple dates stored as text

```
07082020 05092020 10122020
05062020 13052020
25122020 04032020 10112020
```

I want to convert it like this "ddmmmyyyy"

```
07Aug2020 05Sep2020 10Dec2020
05Jun2020 13May2020
25Dec2020 04Mar2020 10Nov2020
```

Date format change didn't work. I thought if I change the string to 07-08-2020 it might recognize. First I tried

```
=regexreplace(D2,"2020","-2020")
```

It worked but I don't know how to insert - after 2 digits.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming from your post that your raw strings begin in D2, try placing the following formula into cell 2 of a column that is otherwise open from Row 2 down:

`=ArrayFormula(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(" "&D2:D,D2:D<>"")," ([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})"," $1-$2-$3"),"-01-","Jan"),"-02-","Feb"),"-03-","Mar"),"-04-","Apr"),"-05-","May"),"-06-","Jun"),"-07-","Jul"),"-08-","Aug"),"-09-","Sep"),"-10-","Oct"),"-11-","Nov"),"-12-","Dec")))`

The core of this is the REGEXREPLACE:

`REGEXREPLACE(FILTER(" "&D2:D,D2:D<>"")," ([0-9]{2})([0-9]{2})([0-9]{4})"," $1-$2-$3")`

A space is prepended to all entries in D2:D that are not blank (as assessed by FILTER). This is to achieve uniformity throughout each string (i.e., space-digits, space-digits, etc.).

Then REGEXREPLACE looks for the space followed by three groupings (shown in parenthesis): digits{2}, digits{2}, digits{4}. Each of those groupings is numbered in REGEX; so we can replace that pattern with Pattern1-dash-Pattern2-dash-Pattern3-dash.

From there, the wrapping SUBSTITUTE calls just replace each occurrence of "-01-","-02-", etc. with the corresponding three-letter month-name equivalent.

This one array formula should process the entire column of D2:D strings.

There are other approaches that could be used (involving SPLIT, JOIN and TRANSPOSE); but this approach, while perhaps looking "long," is probably the easiest to understand.

Answer (score 2):

As @Erik Tyler say, you can SPLIT strings, [convert](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/converting-a-number-to-a-month-name/734b3f7c-eac7-4ca8-937d-935870346fed?msgId=483a743e-89cc-4d9a-9ef3-2a9e1aad8aa2) numbers to Month Name, and then JOIN all results:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN(" ",
                         MID(TEXT(SPLIT(A1," "),"00000000"),1,2) &
                 TEXT(29*MID(TEXT(SPLIT(A1," "),"00000000"),3,2),"mmm") &
                            RIGHT(SPLIT(A1," "),4)
             ))
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could try:

[image]

Formula in `B1`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TEXTJOIN(" ",,TEXT(DATEVALUE(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(A1,"(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d{4})","$1-$2-$3")," ")),"ddmmmyyyy")))
```

Comment: Hi This is exactly what I was looking for. I have not figured out how to do this with regexreplace. Great!

Comment: Hi @JvdV, It seems your formula depends on the time format on Googlesheet, my result `A1=08Jul2020 09May2020 12Oct2020` (date and month are reversed)

Comment: @DangD.Khanh, yes I guess it does, but since I appear to have the same time format as op "dd-mmm-yyyy" I think it should work for him.